# Bluetooth Nearby In Android

Tags: android

I want to create an app in which the core functionality is to notify users if they are in close range with each other.
For Example, my app is installed in devices A and B
If A is near B
Both devices should get a notification.
Without being paired by bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would have to keep the device ID of the users and then when another device is detected nearby (say user B), verify if that device has your app installed on it. If it does, then you can notify user A that there is someone in range.

Your post doesn't contain much more information on the problem, but in theory that is what would need to be done.

Some form of identification needs to be stored and then verified when a new device is detected.

Comment: I got ua point everything u said is correct i just want to know the whole app is in offline and i want to check nearby device via bluetooth
I want to find is it possible with the help of bluetooth to find out if the app is preesnt on it or not

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi: "is it possible with the help of bluetooth to find out if the app is preesnt on it or not" -- generally no, for obvious privacy and security reasons. At most, you could determine whether your app is running and is advertising some Bluetooth service. Generally, apps do not do that continuously, for power reasons in addition to privacy ones.

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi: That is why the contact tracing work being done -- such as [Apple and Google's much-discussed solution](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/04/apple-and-google-detail-bold-and-ambitious-plan-to-track-covid-19-at-scale/) -- is such a technical challenge, one that not even Internet giants can solve completely.

Comment: Unless you cache all the users that have your app installed on the local memory of the device, it  won't be possible for the device to know who has it and who doesn't.

Comment: I also agree with @CommonsWare, it is a very technical challenge. It would be possible if you had internet access, because you could then store the device ID, but that in itself has privacy breach implications.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification @CommonsWare and LunarAI
Is there any other alternative for the above prob

Comment: If privacy is not an issue for you or your users, for instance let's say you and some friends want to use this application and they know you are storing their information, and you also are able to have internet access, yes it's possible. If you don't have internet access you can store all users locally and update them as you have an active connection again.